# Node.js and MongoAtlas - How can I connect to multiple databases in the same application?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-atlas

I'm writing a Node.js cli in which I've to read from one Mongo Atlas DB and write to another Mongo Atlas DB. I'll be reading documents from one db and writing equivalent documents in the other db, one document at a time. I've two separate connection files like this:

### ReadDB.js:

```
require('dotenv').config();
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const read_db_url = process.env.READDB_URI;
const readDB = async () => {
    try {
        await mongoose.connect(read_db_url,
            { 
                useNewUrlParser: true, 
                useUnifiedTopology: true,
                dbName: "dbProd"
            }
        );
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
    }
}

module.exports = readDB
```

### WriteDB.js:

```
require('dotenv').config();
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const write_db_url = process.env.WRITEDB_URI;

const writeDB = async () => {
    try {
        await mongoose.connect(write_db_url,
            { 
                useNewUrlParser: true, 
                useUnifiedTopology: true,
                dbName: "dbQA"
            }
        );
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
    }
}

module.exports = writeDB
```

This what I've so far for the main application (`cli.js`):

### cli.js:

```
require('dotenv').config();
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const connectReadDB = require('./ReadDB.js');
const connectWriteDB = require('./WriteDB.js');

connectReadDB();
connectWriteDB();

const findProduct = async (productId) => {
    products = await Products.find({_id:productId});
}
```

I guess my confusion is how Node.js will know which db to read from to begin with? Will I need separate set of models, one for read and one for write? How can I establish two simultaneous connections in the same Node.js app?

Answer (score 0):

Mongoose handling connections via connections pool http://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html

You can use server: {poolSize: 5} option for increase/decrease pool (number of parallel connections)

If you need connections to different databases look here Mongoose and multiple database in single node.js project

Example of multiple connections:

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const connection = mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://localhost/db1');
const connection2 = mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://localhost/db2');
const Schema = new mongoose.Schema({})
const model1 = connection.model('User', Schema);
const model2 = connection2.model('Item', Schema);

model1.find({}, function() {
   console.log("this will print out last");
});
model2.find({}, function() {
   console.log("this will print out first");
});
```